# I have a table without any primary key and i want it all duplicate records

Tags: sql

I have a table without any primary key and I want it all duplicate records
Table --

```
EmpName  City
-------------
Shivam   Noida
Ankit    Delhi
Mani     Gurugram
Shivam   Faizabad
Mukesh   Noida
```

and want output like this --

```
EmpName  City
-------------
Shivam   Noida   
Shivam   Faizabad
Mukesh   Noida
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nice.  What is the logic behind that output (I don't see it)?

Comment: Also, please tell us what _type_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually, it's an Interview Question so I asked it.

Comment: Okay. The wording is strange, because these are not duplicate records of course (as Shivam is not Mukesh and Noida is not Faizabad).

Answer (score 3):

I think you want exists:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where (t2.empname = t.empname and t2.city <> t.city) or
                    (t2.city = t.city and t2.empname <> t.empname)
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for all rows where the name or city also appears in another row of the table.

```
select *
from mytable
where city in (select city from mytable group by city having count(*) > 1)
   or empname in (select empname from mytable group by empname having count(*) > 1);
```

You say there is no primary key. This suggests that there can be duplicate rows (same name and city). This makes it impossible in many DBMS to use `EXISTS` here to look up the *other* rows. This is why I am suggesting `IN` and `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

use `exists` and `or` condition

```
with cte as
(
select 'Shivam' as name,  'Noida' as city union all
select 'Ankit' ,   'Delhi' union all
select 'Mani'   ,  'Gurugram' union all
select 'Shivam' ,  'Faizabad' union all
select 'Mukesh' ,  'Noida'

) select t1.* from cte t1 where exists ( select 1 from cte  t2
                                       where t1.name=t2.name
                                        group by name
                                        having count(*)>1
                                )
                                or exists
                                (
                                      select 1 from cte  t2
                                       where t1.city=t2.city
                                        group by city
                                        having count(*)>1
                                )
```

output

```
name    city
Shivam  Noida
Shivam  Faizabad
Mukesh  Noida
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `UNION ALL` to put both types of names in one column. (d1)

`GROUP BY` its result, and use `HAVING` to return only duplicates (d2).

`JOIN`:

```
select EmpName, City
from tablename t1
join (select name from
      (select EmpName name from tablename
       union all
       select City from tablename) d1
      group by name
      having count(*) > 1) d2
  on d2.name in (EmpName, City)
```

Comment: You are doing this, because you'd consider a person named Hampton a "duplicate" with a city called Hampton, too? This may or may not be desired. If it is, then your query is the only appropriate one, if it isn't, then it could lead to wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct * from table 
where col1 in (select col1 from table group by col1 having count(1) > 1)
or col2 in (select col2 from table group by col2 having count(1) > 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the answers already given. And `COUNT(1)` is a murky alternative to `COUNT(*)`. What is does is tell the DBMS to generate a 1 per row and count that row in case the 1 is not null. It is more straight-forward to tell the DBMS to count rows right away, which is what `COUNT(*)` does.

Comment: count(*) takes longer ; try running both queries in a table with millions of rows. Try to see which one finishes within a life span. My solution makes more sense than your solution, Thorsten.

Comment: Plus, your solution runs the risk of returning duplicate rows. (no PK remember?)

Comment: As to `COUNT`: This is plain wrong. Look up `COUNT` in the docs for your DBMS (or in the SQL standard docs chapter 4 "Aggregate functions" for that matter). You are using `COUNT(<value expression>`) which counts all rows for which the expression (`1` in your case) is not null. If the DBMS does so blindly that can take a lot of time. Most DBMS, however silently convert your `COUNT(1)` to `COUNT(*)` internally to avoid unnecessary work. `COUNT(1)` can never be faster than `COUNT(*)`; in the best case it's just as fast.

Comment: And yes, my query purposely returns duplicate rows, because this is what's being asked after all. If the duplication is about two rows having both the same name and the same city, I show them both, so the user actually sees where the duplication occurs.

Comment: most DBMS do that? Oracle does that, period. This question is tagged as SQL Server. We should get our facts straight, don't you think? Second, count(1) does not consider all columns to do the counting, it only considers the boolean value of 1. Have you fixed the duplicate rows in your solution ? You are too concerned with my solution and you have not fixed yours yet.

Comment: You are obviously just focused on tables with row numbers in the hundreds. You should get some real field experience. If you return duplicate rows in tables with millions of rows, the user will not be able to tell that your query returned duplicate rows.

Comment: I've worked with databases for more than twenty years, some spanning thousands of tables and tables with several millions of rows. So I think I know what I'm talking about. Did you even look up `COUNT` now? Do you still not understand what `COUNT(1)` does when taken literally by the DBMS? Oracle, SQL Server, etc. have good optimizers and they know that all you want to do is count rows (`COUNT(*)`) and do so internally. But this is because they see your fault. There were times when this was different and `COUNT(1)` could result in unnecessary work and much longer run times.

Comment: As to the query result: well, this is dubious anyway. It's an interview question with a given result as mentioned already. With thousands of rows you'd have some name and city reported and then have to scroll down to find some row where either the name or city or both occur again. This is far from being practical. Of course in reality we would write something different, say an aggregation with counts for same name, same city, same pair. But this is not what's being asked.

Comment: By the way: This question is not tagged SQL Server. How did you get that idea? Anyway, here is Microsoft saying that they convert `COUNT(1)` to `COUNT(*)` internally: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31795984-ea62-4b2c-8c78-6e986f2bcea0/count-1-vs-count-?forum=transactsql